# Fit stack of stone of varying length into a well of varying length

Tags: algorithms, data-structures

I have a stack of m stones of different Diameter.

```
stack = [5,4,9,20,1]
```

And a Well that is of depth n with varying diameter at different depths .

```
wellDiameters = [7,9,1,25,6,7]
```

EDIT:

Only one stone from the top of stack can be taken and after placing that we can take the next stone.

Each level can fit only one stone.

Now I need to make an algo to find the number of maximum stones I can place in well. Now I can place 5 in diameter 9 and  then 4 on top of it as diameter 5 stone can not get fit into 1.

So the answer is 2

The algo I used is brute-force and hence its order O(m*n).

```
count=0
filledIndex =len(wellDiameters)
for stoneDia in stack
     for wellDia in wellDiameters
         if index (wellDia) > filledIndex
            break
         if stoneDia < wellDia
            continue
         else
            count +=1 
            filledIndex = index (wellDia) -1
```

I need to know if there are any faster way to get the count.

Comment: Can each level of the well hold only one stone? That is, you can not put the 4 diameter and the 5 diameter stones side by side at the same level, correct?

And you have to pull the stones off the top of the stack and put them in straight in the well, right? That is what I am getting from what you have written.

Comment: Please give full detail of the problem. Can multiple stones be placed at the same level? Is the list of diameters given from top to bottom or from bottom to top? Do the stones have to be in the order they appear in the input? (If so, is that top-to-bottom or bottom-to-top?)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in $O(n\log(n))$ time (I am assuming they are the same length since, if one is longer, you just treat it like it is only its first $n$ elements, where $n$ is the length of the shorter array). Here is a hint --

First, you should preprocess the well diamater array to make it easier to check a stack of stones against.

Then, you should binary search for how large of a stack you can fit.

I can edit my response to include a more detailed answer if you would like, but I don't want to spoil the problem as you only asked if there were a faster way.

Comment: Thanks a way to think is much more helpful to evolve. I will try it and get back with answer.

Comment: Did you manage to figure it out?